# How to calculate the amount of ID monthly with the condition?

Tags: oracle

I have two joined tables (logging and current).

```
with t as (
select id, status, date from table -- unique id
union all
select id, status, date from table_log) --not unique id

select * from t
order by id, mdf_date desc
```

I have a time interval 01/01/2018 - 08/01/2019.

How can I calculate how many id were at the beginning of each month in status = 3.

I would like to have the following for output:

```
date       count(distinct id)
--------------------
01.01.2018   8567
01.02.2018   8974
01.03.2018   9001
...
01.03.2019   8845 (id = 135 not count)
...
01.08.2019   9567
```

for example

[image]

if max(date) between min(date) and '01.05.2018' and status = 3 => **count** //max(date) = 10.04.2018

if max(date) between min(date) and '01.03.2019' and status != 3 => **not count** //max(date) = 06.02.2019

```
 with t as ( SELECT 135 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate-1 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 135 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate-2 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 135 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate-3 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 135 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate-40 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate-1 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate-55 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate-33 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate-40 AS dte FROM dual)

 select id,status, max(dte) as max_dte from t
 where trunc(t.dte) <= '01.08.2019'
 group by id, status
 order by id, max_dte desc
```

I would like to have the following for output:

```
date         count(distinct id)
--------------------
01.07.2019   0
01.08.2019   3
01.09.2019   2
```

Comment: you need to use `groupBy date`

Comment: Logic is not clear. Please edit the question and describe the logic clearly

Comment: @Tejash It is necessary to take the maximum date at the beginning of the period and if the status of the record = 3, then calculate it.

Comment: And `status = 3` Need to be checked for that maximum date or for all dates in that interval?

Comment: @Tejash I added an example, only the maximum date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not create a SQL=( I did it through the procedure.

```
declare
  v_cnt integer;
begin
  for i in (with t as
               (select to_date('01-06-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') d1,
                      to_date('01-09-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') d2
                 from dual)
              select decode(level,1,d1,trunc(add_months(d1, level - 1), 'mm')) as date_from,
                     case
                       when add_months(trunc(d1, 'mm'), level) > d2 then d2
                       else last_day(add_months(d1, level - 1))
                     end date_to
                from t
              connect by add_months(trunc(d1, 'mm'), level - 1) <= d2) loop

    with t as
     (select id, status, max(dte) as dte
        from (SELECT 135 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate - 1 AS dte FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 135 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate - 2 AS dte FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 135 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate - 3 AS dte FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 135 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate - 40 AS dte FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 3 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate - 1 AS dte FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate - 55 AS dte FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate - 33 AS dte FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 4 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate - 40 AS dte FROM dual) tt

       where trunc(tt.dte) <= i.date_from
       group by id, status
       order by id, dte desc)

    select count(1)
      into v_cnt
      from t
      join (select id, max(dte) as max_dte from t group by id) t2
        on t.id = t2.id and t.dte = t2.max_dte
     where t.status = 3;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.date_from || ' - ' || v_cnt);
  end loop;
end;
```

If anyone can tell how to rationalize or help make a request, I will be grateful)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert each date to the first of the month, then simply count the ids.
something like this ?

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate-1 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS status, sysdate-2 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate-3 AS dte FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, 3 AS status, sysdate-40 AS dte FROM dual
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(dte - (TO_CHAR(dte,'DD'))+1,'dd.mm.yyyy'),count(id) 
FROM t
WHERE status<>3
GROUP BY dte - (to_char(dte,'DD'))+1
```

Comment: there's an easier way of getting to the first of the month - `trunc(<date>, 'mm')`. You can truncate to different elements of the date (year, hour, etc); day is the default to truncate to if you don't specify the second parameter.